# swiftui onDelete doesn't work on sortedData

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an array which is shown as a list, the onDelete button works as expected, func looking like this:

```
func removeGames(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        listGames.games.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
```

but if I sort my array, then this function delete wrong entries

I sort it like this:

```
ForEach(listGames.games.sorted(by: {$0.self.dateOfGame>$1.self.dateOfGame}))
```

Anybody knows, how to make onDelete work as expected?

Comment: The problem is that you delete by matching the index of the (sorted) item on the _unsorted_ array. You can solve this in many ways, one of which would be to sort your array beforehand and use _that_ array instead (for both iteration & deletion).